# Delay in microphone starting to pick up words

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, drivers, microphone

I've used the same microphone and computer for a few months, and it's worked fine, mostly for web meetings.  Starting 1-2 months ago, issues with people not hearing me talk started to crop up.  Typically, the first 1-5 seconds of me speaking won't be heard; it seems like there's some overly aggressive noise filtering going on.  So, what is causing this and how can I stop it?

Observations:

- Occurs on 2 of the same webcam and on a completely different microphone.
- Occurs on 2 different programs (Windows Voice Recorder and Zoom).
- Does not occur in those programs with those devices on another computer.
- In the Zoom desktop application, under advanced audio settings, if I set the "signal processing by Windows audio device drivers" to off, then the issue goes away within Zoom (but not elsewhere, of course).  This is true for both the discrete microphone and the webcam mic.
- Same is true if I go into my discrete microphone's properties and uncheck a bout about permitting signal processing by the audio device.  This removes the delay everywhere, but, it also disables all signal processing, so microphone input has noise, popping, etc.
- Dell Optiplex desktop, Windows 10, updated drivers.

As to what is doing the problematic signal processing, here's what I've found under Device Manager:

- Audio inputs and outputs: This just lists the physical devices I've used.
- Sound, video and game controllers -> Intel(R) Display Audio
- Sound, video and game controllers -> NVIDIA High Definition Audio
- Sound, video and game controllers -> Realtek(R) Audio
- System Devices -> High Definition Audio Controller: there are two of these, manufacturer is Microsoft

Comment: I think the signal processing was the problematic item for you (i.e. you solved it). Signal processing is another way to say "mess with the signal". This will have an aural impact but also potentially introduce latency. Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/audio-signal-processing-modes

Comment: @Yorik yep, I know what signal processing is, but the issue isn't resolved because disabling that checkbox disables ALL processing, so low-level noise, popping, etc. all get through.  I'll clarify the question on this.

Answer (score 0):

Windows audio device drivers tend to go to low power after 5+ seconds, and take 1+ seconds to wake up. It's super annoying, but [there may be a solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1826059/nvidia-high-definition-audio-pops-when-switching-between-power-states) similar to [`tsched=0 in /etc/pulse/default.pa` in GNU/Linux.](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/comments/nw17hs/comment/h172967/)