# NVIDIA High Definition Audio pops when switching between power states

Tags: audio, windows-registry

My NVIDIA High Definition Audio device connected to my LG D2342P monitor via HDMI, produces a pop on my Logitech 2.1 speakers when it switches from power state D0 (on) to D3 (low power) after 6 seconds in Windows 11 Home 23H2. My Target TRG-S 120 did not pop, but unfortunately that hardware fell to its demise, so a software solution should work as well.

Lowering speaker Hz, disabling audio enhancements, disabling other speaker devices, and disabling PCI idling didn't help. I don't even see the speaker in [PowerSettingsExplorer](https://forums.guru3d.com/threads/windows-power-plan-settings-explorer-utility.416058/).

I think a script like [this](https://gist.github.com/supermarsx/e505de8dda4a499f6aa8a552f06f19fe) would help to stop the state transitions, but how to modify it for my device?

```
# Enable Realtek driver power management, this is the default value
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Realtek\RAVCpl64\PowerMgnt" /v "Enabled" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

# Disable Realtek driver power management, sometimes fixes realtek popping sound
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Realtek\RAVCpl64\PowerMgnt" /v "Enabled" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

# Replace XXXX with the corresponding key that has "Realtek" in the "DriverDesc", find using regedit
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e96c-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\XXXX\PowerSettings" /v "IdlePowerState" /t REG_BINARY /d "ffffffff" /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e96c-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\XXXX\PowerSettings" /v "PerformanceIdleTime" /t REG_BINARY /d "ffffffff" /f
# Example if class is in 0000
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e96c-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0000\PowerSettings" /v "IdlePowerState" /t REG_BINARY /d "ffffffff" /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e96c-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0000\PowerSettings" /v "PerformanceIdleTime" /t REG_BINARY /d "ffffffff" /f
```

While not playing audio, my Device Manager says:

[image: Not playing audio. Audio driver sleeps.]

But when I start playing audio, I don't hear the first second or two and the state changes to this:

[image: Playing audio. Audio driver awake.]

Use the arrow keys to update the selected data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In Device Manager device properties, select `Class Guid` and copy the value.
2. Use Registry Editor to find that value folder in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\`
3. Find the numbered folder with the DriverDesc matching your driver (in my case `0005`).
4. Open that folder and select `PowerSettings`
5. Optionally use File, Export to save a back up .reg file.
6. Change the `PerformanceIdleTime` to `00 00 00 00` to have the idle pop occur after 11 instead of 6 seconds and maybe tweak `IdlePowerState` as well:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e96c-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0005\PowerSettings]
"ConservationIdleTime"=hex:04,00,00,00
"IdlePowerState"=hex:00,00,00,00
"PerformanceIdleTime"=hex:00,00,00,00
```

In PowerShell, running `REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e96c-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0005\PowerSettings" /v "IdlePowerState"` now results in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e96c-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0005\PowerSettings
    IdlePowerState    REG_BINARY    00000000
```

But the Power data still says D3. Maybe a reboot helps. Never mind, disabling and enabling the driver worked; Power data now stays on D0 without playing audio!